# Admin sidebar overlapping on editor when saving draft

Tags: post-editor, draft

I am having this weird problem. Everytime I save a draft, the sidebar's black area appears and overlaps the editor making the editor unusable. It also attempts to save the draft repetitively and the only way to get out of it is to refresh the page. Kindly refer to the following image. 
[image: inspecting it revealed nothing odd though]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You'll need to identify the source of the issue, either by manually inspecting the document to find the relevant style rules or by the routine troubleshooting dance (switch to a default theme; if the problem persists, disable all plugins and enable them again one by one - or the reverse - until you identify which change, if any, alleviated the issue). In the case that the problem is the result of a third-party plugin or theme, the product's support channels may be able to offer you more assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of WP Native Articles here. This is normally a problem with other plugins incorrectly messing around with  tag incorrectly and preventing it from setting the correct URL. If you save this code below as a separate file, upload it as a plugin and activate it it should fix it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPNA Editor Fix
 * Description: Fix the base URL meta field that other plugins break.
 * Author: OzTheGreat (WPArtisan)
 * Author URI: https://wpartisan.me
 * Version: 1.0.1
 * Plugin URI: https://wp-native-articles.com
 *
 * @package wpna-editor-fix
 */

add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'wpna_custom_fix_base_url' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpna_custom_fix_base_url' );

function wpna_custom_fix_base_url(){
    ?>
    <script>
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            var bases = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
            if (bases.length > 0) {
                bases[0].href = document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Tested it and it worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out! It was caused by WP Native Articles' Premium plug-in. I'm now talking to the developer and if there is anything concrete, I will update here.